# How do I make the text in the SVG full?

Tags: svg, text

```
<svg width="714" height="156">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="714" height="156" stroke="red" stroke-width="3px" fill="white"/>
    <text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="100%">TEST</text>    
</svg>
```

[image]

I want to draw a border on a certain size of svg and make it full of letters like this.
(There's a little bit of upper space in the picture below, but I want to make sure there's no space.)
[image]

How I can stretch the text to fit container?

Comment: Add a scale transform

Comment: @RobertLongson Thank you for your answer. If you don't mind, could you explain it in more detail?

Comment: @RobertLongson Sorry, I'm not familiar with this task, so I asked you a question. I'll look for it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform

Comment: @RobertLongson Thank you for the link. I'll refer to it.